# How to extract text using DoodleNerd's CSS textboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently used DoodleNerd's CSS Textbox Generator (http://doodlenerd.com/html-control/css-textbox-generator) to make a really sleek looking textbox for my website. I'm familiar with extracting text from forms; I've done it in two main forms:

```js
document.getElementById('field').value

or 

driver.findElement(By.id("field")).getCssValue("value")
```

For some reason, when I use DoodleNerd's textboxes, the values in the box aren't extracted... it's really odd.. I'll include my css and html for reference:

```css
#field {
        position: absolute;
        left: 33px;
        top: 170px;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 129px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Comic Sans MS;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgba(249,249,249);
    }
.field {
     padding: 0px;
     font-size: 15px;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-color: #CCCCCC;
     background-color: #ba6fc5;
     color: #f9f9f9;
     border-style: inset;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px rgba(66,66,66,.75);
     text-shadow: 49px -11px 5px rgba(177,37,37,.0);
}
 .field:focus {
     outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
        <input type="text" value="e.g. '999'" class="field" />
    </div>
```

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like the value you want is: e.g '999' correct? If so, this should be your JavaScript:

```
var fieldValue = document.querySelector('.field').value;
```

It appears like the value you want has the class of field, not the id of field.

If you must use document.getElementById(), you could also do this:

```
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var value = field.firstElementChild.value;
```

But I think the first way is probably better.